# How to align column-widths in 2 tables?

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-4

I have two tables that are semantically different, so they should be kept separate, IMHO. However, I'd like to align their columns. Browsing SO I found that column widths in a table can be controlled by setting `w-`-classes in the `thead`. This worked fine for the 2nd table (which was the ine I started with). But when I added the first table on top of it, desaster struck - not only do their columns not align, even the relation of column-widths does not seem to correspond to the `w-`-values.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/fbo0L88v/).

`thead`of table1:

```
<thead class="bg-secondary">
  <tr>
    <th class="w-8">Model Name</th>
    <th class="w-8">Y</th>
    <th class="w-15">S</th>
    <th class="w-15">R<sup>2</sup>(%)</th>
    <th class="w-15">R<sup>2</sup>-Adj (%)</th>
    <th class="w-39">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

and table2:

```
<thead class="bg-secondary">
  <tr>
    <th class="w-8">Var</th>
    <th class="w-8">Include</th>
    <th class="w-15">Expression</th>
    <th class="w-15">Coefficient</th>
    <th class="w-15">StdErr</th>
    <th class="w-15">T</th>
    <th class="w-15">P</th>
    <th class="w-9">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `w-8`,`w-15` etc... in Bootstrap 4.

The width sizing classes are `w-25`, `w-50`, `w-75`, `w-100` and `w-auto`.

Refer to the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/sizing/

Comment: So, recomping Bootstrap to get the required classes turned out to be not as easy as I would have liked - I finally ended up at https://bootstrap.build/ which made building that custom.css a breeze. Wish I had done found the site earlier...

Comment: @MBaas - There's also [whootstrap](http://whootstrap.themes.guide) if you're looking for a customizer/theme builder.